# Compare Video file from file/content uri

Tags: javascript, file, react-native, buffer, uri

So I have 2 uri, the first one is `file://` uri, the second one is `content://` uri.

Both of them are .mp4 files.

**Example:**

File URI: `file:///data/user/0/com.rncourse/cache/Camera/2567b45c-c7e2-4fb6-8144-38b1cbceb1b8.mp4`

Content URI: `content://media/external/video/media/485371`

Having that being said, all of my videos have similarities like

1. Same video duration (3 seconds)
2. Same width & height (4:3)
3. Same resolution (640x480p)
4. Same mime type (video/mp4)

The only difference will be the content of the video.

I'm using `react-native-camera` to record the video.

---

Now I wanted to compare these 2 video file, to see if these are the same or different content.

FYI, I'm using React-Native. Any Javascript/React-Native modules/libraries are welcome. :)

The idea was:

1. Get video files
2. Convert to buffer
3. Compare the buffer

Any suggestion as to get this result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-native-video`

The video module can be used for direct comparison or the value of the onload of the module can be compared to check if it is different.

**onLoad**
Callback function that is called when the media is loaded and ready to play.[image: onload]

Comment: I have seen `react-native-video` before, but I still don't know how to compare video with it, can you please kindly show me the example of how to do it? As well as how you load a video by using `react-native-video`. Thank you.

Comment: I have added more explanation, please do help if you know other solution to compare video. Thanks!